# Speed and Temperature Data History for JWST?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, raw-data

Is there a source for data on velocity and various temperatures of JWST?

I would like to see a graph of the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to find the data to graph JWST temperature since launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57625/where-to-find-the-data-to-graph-jwst-temperature-since-launch) The answer(s) there show where to find both. *Welcome to Space SE!*